# Printing on CTEXT widget in C++ MFC app

Tags: c++, mfc, windows-ce

I'm working on pagination for my C++ app - I want to show currentPage / allPages on CTEXT and I'm having hard time making the printing functionality work.

This is how's widget configured in .rc file (I don't mind switching from CTEXT to any other

```
IDD_PIC_PLAYER_DIALOG DIALOG  0, 0, 400, 247
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_FIXEDSYS | DS_CENTER | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE
EXSTYLE WS_EX_APPWINDOW | 0x80000000L
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg"

BEGIN
    CTEXT           "Static",IDC_PG,211,183,65,62
END
```

Widget has .bmp background I'm intending to be writing on.

```
IDB_PG                  BITMAP                  "res\\pg.bmp"
```

This is how my code looks like :

```
TCHAR szPageText[64] = TEXT("");
wsprintf(szPageText, TEXT("%d of %d"), iCurSelPage, m_iPageCount);    
this->SetDlgItemText(IDC_PG, szPageText);
```

Code compiles, but does not doing what it's supposed to do - print those 2 integers.
If anybody knows what piece of puzzle am I missing here - I'd be grateful.

Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @MichaelWalz could you be little more descriptive please

Comment: You write that it is not doing what it is supposed to do, but then _what_  is it doing instead?

Comment: Forget my first comment, I deleted it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz just nothing. There should be either semantical problem with my code which I dont see, or whole idea of printing on bmp background in CTEXT is wrong - but to my very best knowledge and understanding of documentation - thats correct way how to realize it. .

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong in your code. Try to simplify your code until the problem goes away. Especially remove the bmp displaying stuff.